# '\xa0' and '\xb' characters in RS-232 readout using pySerial on MacOS

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, hex, byte

I cannot seem to figure out why I am receiving hex characters ('/xa0', '/xb', etc.) when connecting to a laboratory balance via an RS-232 connection. I am using Python 3.7 with the pySerial library to read the output data from the balance.

Here is the code to retrieve this data:

```
import re
import serial

class Scale:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(
        #port='/dev/ttyUSB0', # RPi
        port='/dev/tty.usbserial', # MACOS
        baudrate = 2400,
        parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
        timeout=None
        )

    def get_value(self):
        byte_val = self.ser.readline()
        return byte_val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Scale().get_value())
```

For example, if I print a value from a scale, I will receive the output:

```
>>> b'S\xa0S\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xb1\xb45.9\xb1\xa0\xe7\x8d\n'
```

When in reality, the output should have `145.91`, uninterrupted. If you look closely, the values that comprise 145.91 lies in the hex output.

I am wondering if there is an error in the RS-232 communication with pySerial?

Comment: I guess you are getting wrong value. When I tried to convert the above value it gives me "SS5.9" something like this

Comment: are you sure it sends value as raw text, not compressed or encoded ? Do you have the same problem on differrnt computer and system?